# Create fast a vector from in sequential values

Tags: c++

How can I to create fast a vector from in sequential values

Eg.:

```
vector<int> vec (4, 100);
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Out:

```
# 100
# 100
# 100
# 100
```

I want

```
vector<int> vec (100, "0 to N");
```

I want to know the most efficient way to achieve this result. For example, without using the loop.

N it a runtime variable.

Comment: You do understand you will be using a loop *somewhere*, right?

Comment: Yes, but I would leave the clean code!

Comment: Well, loops don't necessarily make code dirty... less lines don't make ease of reading an undeniable fact. But it was an interesting question afterall :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a version not using a visible loop and only the standard C++ library. It nicely demonstrates the use of a lambda as generator, too. The use of `reserve()` is optional and just intended to avoid more than one memory allocation.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);
int n(0);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 100, [n]()mutable { return n++; });
```

Comment: @HappyYellowFace: I have no idea and and can imagine either be better: the copying a range of integers can process multiple integers at once but it also touches more memory. The code above probably can get unrolled and the compiler may look through the lambda. It would be necessary to measure to find out for sure and I can image that it depends on the implementation of `std::generate_n()`, too: the standard library could look through the `std::back_inserter()` and even do the `reserve()` automatically.

Comment: This could be simplified to `std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 100, [&](){ return v.size(); });`

Answer (score 23):

Here's another way...

```
int start = 27;
std::vector<int> v(100);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), start);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> second(
    boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(0U),
    boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(99U));
```

Comment: @Cornstalks: The iterator is a random access iterator (in this case), so only one allocation will occur.

Comment: @GManNickG: `std::vector`'s constructor takes an InputIterator, not a RandomAccessIterator. Unless the implementation has a special case for a RandomAccessIterator, it will have to repeatedly grow, as an InputIterator doesn't have a way to give you the range of two iterators.

Comment: @Cornstalks: That's exactly what I'm saying. Any basic `std::vector` implementation (and all *real* implementations) specializes for random access iterators. The constructor only specifies the weakest allowable  iterator, it can do whatever it wants with the actual iterator.

Comment: @Cornstalks: any self-respecting implementation of `std::vector<T>` will determine the size of the sequence for random access iterators if this is what is passed to the constructor! It merely takes a minor amount of template hackery to specialize the processing for the case that the template argument is a random access iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Using the generate algorithm :

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::generate
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <iterator>

// function generator:
struct one_more { 
  int _count;
  one_more() : _count(0) {}
  int operator()() {
      return _count++;
  }
};

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector (100);
  std::generate (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), one_more());

  std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const int num_seconds = 100;
vector<int> second( num_seconds );
for( int n = 0 ; n < num_seconds ; ++n ) {
    second[ n ] = n;
}
```

Comment: I would not want to use loop. Is there another way?

Comment: @AlanValejo: Every answer will have a loop, visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but I am currently playing with [library](http://github.com/dawikur/htl) to handle exactly this problem. It requires c++14.

```
#include "htl.hpp"

htl::Token _;

std::vector<int> vec = _[0, _, 100];
// or
for (auto const e: _[0, _, 100]) { ... }
```