# How to create a row vector with elements from 0 up to and including N in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, armadillo

I would like to create a row vector in C++ with integer elements from and including 0 to N (an integer variable I assign in my C++ program). I have seen the Armadillo C++ library and tried using its `span` function but it does not create a vector (rather creates an object with type `arma::span`) so writing:

```
vec n = span(0,N);
```

does not create the desired vector. If it helps (like if my explanation of what I want is unclear) I know that in MATLAB this creates the vector I want:

```
n=0:N;
```

I do not really care which library (if any) is used, provided the library is available on most major Linux distributions (like my present one, Fedora 25).

Comment: Can you give an example of your required output. Is it just a vector like {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, where N=9? If so maybe [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)?

Comment: Yeah, just a vector nothing special, just like you described in your example.

Comment: OK, well if you can show me how I can use `std::iota` to create a vector `n` with elements of (and including) `0` to `N` I'll accept your answer.

Comment: [Create fast a vector from in sequential values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18625223/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::iota` like so.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int N = 9;
    std::vector<int> n(N + 1);
    std::iota(begin(n), end(n), 0);

    for(auto i: n)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Theres probably also a cool way to do it at compile time using `std::integer_sequence` and some metaprogramming.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by this answer because you seemed to have switched my vector variable `n` with `x`. Have you?

Comment: yes. I didnt consider the name of the variable as important. I can rename it to n in the answer no problem. Although thats very similar to `N`.

Comment: Although TBH neither `n` nor `x` are very descriptive names.

Comment: n is one I've used for many years in MATLAB, so it has a very specific meaning to me.

Comment: Although in the context of such a short piece of educational code, its not really critical to have descriptive names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) like this:

```
std::vector<int> v(n + 1);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Or you could wrap that up into a function like this:

```
inline std::vector<int> zero_to_n_vector(std::size_t n)
{
    std::vector<int> v(n + 1);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    return v;
}

auto v = zero_to_n_vector(20);
```