# How to multiply a vector and scalar in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to multiply a vector with a scalar. This vector was created using the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030499/how-to-create-a-row-vector-with-elements-from-0-up-to-and-including-n-in-c) of mine namely:

```
std::vector<int> n(N + 1);
  std::iota(begin(n), end(n), 0);
```

and I would like to multiply this vector, `n`, with a scalar (specifically of type double, if it is relevant here) called `npi`.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3885095/1876983) to a previous question here, but it wasn't all that helpful. The way I attempted to implement it was by adding:

```
std::transform(n.begin(), n.end(), n.begin(),
           std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),pin));
```

to my C++ program. This returned the compile error:

```
error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
                std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),pin));
```

I would like to call the vector created by multiplying this vector with a scalar `npi`, so please do not give me code that will call this new vector `n` (i.e., overwriting my existing `n` vector).

**EDIT:**

If it will placate whomever voted to close this question, here is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
/*#include <armadillo>*/

using namespace std;
/*using namespace arma;*/

double N  = 1000.0;
double x0 = 0;
double x1 = 100;
double pin = M_PI / double(N);

int main() {
  std::vector<int> n(N + 1);
  std::iota(begin(n), end(n), 0);
  std::transform(n.begin(), n.end(), n.begin(),
               std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),pin));
  for(double i: n)
  {
    std::cout << i << '\n' << std::scientific;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your vector is int.  If you multiply it by a double scalar the values in the vector will still be int - the destination vector needs to be double so if you are going to modify in place change your vector<int> to vector<double>

Comment: `double(N)` is a C-style cast. Casts are best avoided wherever possible (it's not needed here as N is already a double). If one is necessary, best to use C++-style `static_cast<double>(N)` instead.

Comment: I *think* `begin(foo)` and `foo.begin()` are always equivalent (not certain though), in which case it's best to stick to one style throughout. This is a very minor and probably over-pedantic point, but consistency makes clearer code!

Comment: `N` is already a double, so the cast is not necessary.

Comment: Please clarify what `npi` should be -- `vector<int>`, `vector<double>`, or something else?  Your existing code tries to modify `n` in-place (therefore giving `vector<int>` output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `T` by the type contained in the vector, in this case `int`. However you can probably simplify your code by using a lambda function here instead:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::transform
#include <cmath>     // for M_PI
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout etc
#include <numeric>   // for std::iota
#include <vector>    // for awesome

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec1(10);
  std::iota(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), 0);

  int N = 42;

  std::vector<double> vec2(vec1.size()); // vec2 needs to be as big or bigger than vec1

  std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(),
                 [N](int i) { return i * M_PI / N; });

  for (auto a : vec1)
    std::cout << a << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (auto a : vec2)
    std::cout << a << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here's an online example: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XrNxDND0steJmym8

Comment: Will this store the result as `n` (hence overwriting my `n` vector)?

Comment: Yes, this will. There's probably a way to write the output of `std::transform` to a new vector though... stand by...

Comment: Is it also worthwhile noting that `pin` isn't an integer? It's `pi/N` where N is an integer. Doesn't that mean the type `double` should be used?

Comment: No problem - I've expanded the example. You probably don't need to use `std::bind1st(std::multiplies` though.

Answer (score 3):

For `vector<int>` output, one way is:

```
auto npi = n;

for( auto& i: npi )
    i *= pin;
```

If `npi` should be `vector<double>` (not clear from the question) then replace the first line with:

```
std::vector<double> npi( n.begin(), n.end() );
```

Comment: That would work if the OP wants to have a `vector<int>` but OP wants a `vector<double>` as the output. Otherwise, this is very pleasingly concise!

Comment: @JackDeeth OP didn't say that he wanted a `vector<double>` output. And his original code attempts to do the transformation in-place, suggesting that he intended `vector<int>` output; although he says in comments that he doesn't want to overwrite the original vector.

Comment: @MM It did not occur to me that `int a = int b * double c` could be a useful thing. Good call!

Comment: @JackDeeth you're probably right but I can imagine some applications for integer result (e.g. working on a lattice instead of continuous space)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly you need the following

```
std::vector<double> v;
v.reserve(n.size());

std::transform(n.begin(), n.end(), std::back_inserter( v ),
    std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(), pin));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the scalar in the capture clause of the Lambda function and do the multiplication inside the lambda function itself

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    
    std::vector<int> foo; 
    std::vector<int> bar;
    auto npi=4.0;
    std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(), [&npi](auto& c){return c * npi;}
```